# LINQ to XML adds null item to object list

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My xml:

```
  <Configuration>
    <LaunchDebugger>false</LaunchDebugger>
    <RequestFolder>./Request</RequestFolder>
    <ResponseFolder>./Response</ResponseFolder>
    <Countries>
      <Country NumericCode="1FH" FileName="file1.xml">1</Country>
      <Country NumericCode="20H" FileName="file2.xml">2</Country>
      <Country NumericCode="" FileName="file3.xml">3</Country>
    </Countries>
  </Configuration>
```

Country class:

```
public class Country
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String NumericCode { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
}
```

This is how i create objects from it using LINQ:

```
    CountryList = (from filter in Configuration.Descendants("Countries").Descendants("Country")
                    select new Country() 
                    {
                        Name = (string)filter.Value,
                        NumericCode = (string)filter.Attribute("NumericCode"),
                        FileName = (string)filter.Attribute("FileName")
                    }).ToList();
```

Parsing xml works, i get all 3 countries in my list, but i also get one extra null object as the last item of the list.

[image]

Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: You don't need to coerce `filter.Value` to `string`; it's enough to coerce `filter` alone - `(string)filter` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is simple - `List<T>` has default capacity equal to 4. [Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure can hold without resizing. Internal data structure is a simple array `private Country[] _items`, which is initially has length equal to 4. Thus there is reserved place for forth element, which is null until element assigned. But don't worry - elements count will be `3` if you check.

Here is an image, which shows both public (three items) and internal data structure (array of capacity size)

[image: Internal structure of List]

Comment: And presumably `foreach` will ignore the `null` element.

Comment: @ZevSpitz actually `foreach` enumerates until `size` is reached. Also you can have null elements added to list, which will not be ignored.

Comment: Of course. I meant the `null` included because of the `Capacity`.

Comment: `size` is an internal property of `List<T>`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz yes, but its same as `Count`. Actually count just returns internal `_size`, which increased when item added, and decreased when item removed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the **TrimExcess** method to reduce the capacity to match the count, but this don't work if you have less than 4 elements, like in current question.

Related links: 

**Capasity** method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.100).aspx

**TrimExcess** method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207(v=vs.100).aspx

Question about **default capacity** - [Default Capacity of List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762817/default-capacity-of-list)