# Does C# reserve three null instances ahead of time on a List<Object>?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-embedded-compact

I have the following:

```
 public static class LocalFileModelList
    {
        public static List<LocalFileModel> ModelList = new List<LocalFileModel>();
    }

    public class LocalFileModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
    }
```

Then a method to read all files from a directory.

```
public static List<LocalFileModel> GetAllFiles(string path)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");

    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        var Extension    = Path.GetExtension(file);
        var Filename     = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

        var model = new LocalFileModel
        {
            Name         = Filename,
            Extension    = Extension,
        };

        LocalFileModelList.ModelList.Add(model);     
    }

    return LocalFileModelList.ModelList;
}
```

I noticed that, as I step through my code, when I create a new instance of `LocalFileModel`, populate it with data then add it to the list. Automatically the list created three additional instances of type `null`. Once those three were populated with their respective objects, it would again create thre more null instances...

[image]

I just realized this now, this is normal?

Comment: Yes it's normal, usually the internal buffer increases in size by a factor of ~2 when resizing during an insert.

Comment: Just to clarify the jargon. `null` is not a type and represent a non-instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` has an internal array, with a certain capacity which is *always* equal to or greater than the number of items on the list.

```
list.Capacity >= list.Count
```

You can actually tell the list what capacity its internal array should be created with.

```
new List<int>(capacity: 5);
```

When an item is inserted, and the array is at its capacity, the list creates a new array with double the previous size to accommodate the new element. So, in your case, if you were to insert a 5th item, the list would allocate a new internal array with 8 slots (5 of which would be filled).

For more details, check the implementation [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646,references).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. .NET and most other libraries allocate a list or a vector with extra space (capacity) so it doesn't constantly have to resize and copy the data. The `Size` determines what is accessible.

The default capacity is defined in here to 4 (but the docs doesn't have to be):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,aa9d469618cd43b0,references

Answer (score 1):

The [initial capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762817/default-capacity-of-list) of the internal array held by `List<T>` is 4 (currently, that is an implementation detail and may change), granted you added an initial value. Once you start filling the list, it will resize itself by a multiple of 2 each time. That is why when you know ahead of time the number of minimum items, you can use the overload taking `int capacity` (or use an array if it's really a fixed size).

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` is backed by an array. The default/Initial capaicity of `List<T>` is defined as `4` as in [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,aa9d469618cd43b0,references), but it doesn't take affect until an item is added to a list.

```
 public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
    {
        private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;
```

So when you added the first item in your `List`, the size is set to `4` using the following [check](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,434) in `EnsureCapacity` method:

```
int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
```

Later on, with each new item being added to the list, the capacity increases to `Number of Elements * 2`

That is why, when you add the first item, you can see three `null` spaces, three additional spaces reserved in your list.